# Track SharePoint Changes

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel

I have made a view in my SharePoint from an excel file and want to track the daily/weekly changes. How could I set up something to send out an email weekly to notate what changes were made and what was there before the change? If possible...

Thank you!

Comment: Try the out of the box alerts, you will be able to subscribe for daily or weekly updates.

Comment: This is not a "Document" that I want to track the changes but a "View" in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this out of the box. Below is a workaround which I think will work

1. Create a hidden list which is used to store the changes
2. Create a workflow that runs on item created or updated
3. Make entries to the audit list along with date and time

Now have another workflow that runs every week. You can use Pause Activity for a week and create a loop to kick start this workflow weekly. Inside have logic to get the past week data and put it in email.

If you are open to development then you can do the above using event receivers and timer jobs.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly you want to track changes to list items, right?

1. Powershell script

You can try [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Create-a-report-on-all-fe377c62) to see the changes on your site collection and then filter the ones applying to the list

2. Workflow as Amal Hashim suggested
3. Alerts on the list:
   [image]